# How to change the url of numbers in pagination using CakePHP?

Tags: url, cakephp, pagination

By default, when displaying pagination numbers, the url looks like `/controller/action/page:number`. In my application I have defined a route:

```
Router::connect('/:categ', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'), array('categ' => '[a-zA-Z]+'));
```

I want the number link to be something like `/:categ/:page`.

I've tried with

```
Router::connectNamed(array('page'));
```

but has no effect.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You must using pagination options with url params:`<?php $this->Paginator->options(array('url' => 'some params')); ?>`